# InvalidArgumentError: Incompatible shapes: [10,224,224,3] vs. [10,224,224]

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, tf.keras

I have dataset with more than 10000 images (dim=1024x1024) and I am using tf.keras DataGenerator to load the data in batches. However, when I fit the model using model.fit_generator I get an error: InvalidArgumentError: Incompatible shapes: [10,224,224,3] vs. [10,224,224].
My input dimensions are 224x224x3.

Here is the code snippet:

```
import math
import random
import cv2
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras.utils import Sequence
from tensorflow.keras.applications.mobilenet import preprocess_input

class DataGenerator(Sequence):
    
    def __init__(self, dataset, batch_size=10, shuffle=True, predict=False):        
        self.dataset = dataset
        self.batch_size=batch_size
        self.shuffle=shuffle
        self.predict=predict
        self.on_epoch_end()
    
    def __len__(self):         
        return math.ceil(len(self.dataset)/self.batch_size)    
       
    def __getitem__(self, index):   
        
        indexes = self.indexes[index*self.batch_size:(index+1)*self.batch_size]
        
        image_batch = [self.dataset[i][1]['dicom'] for i in indexes]
        bbox_batch = [self.dataset[i][1]['boxes'] for i in indexes]
        
        X = self.__generate_X(image_batch)
        if self.predict:
            return X
        else:
            masks = self.__generate_masks(image_batch, bbox_batch)
            return X, masks
        
    def __generate_X(self, image_batch): 
        
        X = np.zeros((len(image_batch), IMAGE_WIDTH, IMAGE_HEIGHT,3), dtype=np.float32)
        for k, image_path in enumerate(image_batch):
            img = dicom.read_file(image_path).pixel_array
            img = cv2.resize(img, dsize=(IMAGE_HEIGHT, IMAGE_WIDTH), interpolation=cv2.INTER_CUBIC)
            img = np.stack((img,)*3, axis=-1)
            X[k] = preprocess_input(np.array(img, dtype=np.float32))
        return X
                
    def __generate_masks(self, image_batch, bbox_batch):        
        
        X = np.zeros((len(image_batch), IMAGE_WIDTH, IMAGE_HEIGHT,3), dtype=np.float32)
        for k, image_path in enumerate(image_batch):
            img = dicom.read_file(image_path).pixel_array
            img = cv2.resize(img, dsize=(IMAGE_HEIGHT, IMAGE_WIDTH), interpolation=cv2.INTER_CUBIC)
            img = np.stack((img,)*3, axis=-1)
            X[k] = preprocess_input(np.array(img, dtype=np.float32))         
        return X
                
        masks = np.zeros((len(bbox_batch), IMAGE_WIDTH, IMAGE_HEIGHT))
        width_factor = IMAGE_WIDTH/imageWidth
        height_factor = IMAGE_HEIGHT/imageHeight
        
        for k, bbox_items in enumerate(bbox_batch):
            if len(bbox_items) > 0:
                for idx, val in enumerate(bbox_items):
                    x1 = round(val[0]* width_factor)
                    x2 = round((val[0]+val[2])* width_factor)
                    y1 = round(val[1]*height_factor)  
                    y2 = round((val[1]+val[3])*height_factor)
                    masks[k][y1:y2, x1:x2]=1
                return masks               
    
    def on_epoch_end(self):  
        self.indexes = np.arange(len(self.dataset))      
        if self.shuffle == True:
            np.random.shuffle(self.indexes) 

model = create_model()
optimizer = Adam(lr = 0.001)
model.compile(loss=loss, optimizer=optimizer, metrics=[dice_coefficient])

train_gen = DataGenerator(X_train, batch_size=10,  predict=False, shuffle=True)

model.fit_generator(train_gen, validation_data = None, epochs=1,  verbose=1)
```

The inputs: X_train and X_val are numpy arrays
Tensorflow version: 1.15.0
Keras version: 2.2.4
Here is the error that I get when using fit_generator

```
InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-17-b4c5d8755e72> in <module>
----> 1 model.fit_generator(generator=train_gen, validation_data=None, epochs=1, shuffle=True, verbose=1)
      2 

~\Anaconda3\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training.py in fit_generator(self, generator, steps_per_epoch, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_data, validation_steps, validation_freq, class_weight, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing, shuffle, initial_epoch)
   1294         shuffle=shuffle,
   1295         initial_epoch=initial_epoch,
-> 1296         steps_name='steps_per_epoch')
   1297 
   1298   def evaluate_generator(self,

~\Anaconda3\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training_generator.py in model_iteration(model, data, steps_per_epoch, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_data, validation_steps, validation_freq, class_weight, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing, shuffle, initial_epoch, mode, batch_size, steps_name, **kwargs)
    263 
    264       is_deferred = not model._is_compiled
--> 265       batch_outs = batch_function(*batch_data)
    266       if not isinstance(batch_outs, list):
    267         batch_outs = [batch_outs]

~\Anaconda3\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training.py in train_on_batch(self, x, y, sample_weight, class_weight, reset_metrics)
   1015       self._update_sample_weight_modes(sample_weights=sample_weights)
   1016       self._make_train_function()
-> 1017       outputs = self.train_function(ins)  # pylint: disable=not-callable
   1018 
   1019     if reset_metrics:

~\Anaconda3\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\backend.py in __call__(self, inputs)
   3474 
   3475     fetched = self._callable_fn(*array_vals,
-> 3476                                 run_metadata=self.run_metadata)
   3477     self._call_fetch_callbacks(fetched[-len(self._fetches):])
   3478     output_structure = nest.pack_sequence_as(

~\Anaconda3\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\client\session.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1470         ret = tf_session.TF_SessionRunCallable(self._session._session,
   1471                                                self._handle, args,
-> 1472                                                run_metadata_ptr)
   1473         if run_metadata:
   1474           proto_data = tf_session.TF_GetBuffer(run_metadata_ptr)

InvalidArgumentError: Incompatible shapes: [10,224,224,3] vs. [10,224,224]
     [[{{node training/Adam/gradients/gradients/loss/reshape_loss/mul_2_grad/BroadcastGradientArgs}}]]
```

I would really appreciate any guidance to resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

Did you do the normalization?

For instance:

```
from keras import backend as k

if k.image_data_format() == 'channels_first':
    x_train = x_train.reshape(x_train.shape[0], 1, image_row, image_column)
    x_test = x_test.reshape(x_test.shape[0], 1, image_row, image_column)
    input_shape = (1, image_row, image_column)
else:
    x_train = x_tr.reshape(x_tr.shape[0], image_row, image_column, 1)
    x_test = x_te.reshape(x_te.shape[0], image_row, image_column, 1)
    input_shape = (image_row, image_column, 1)
```

Before training any dataset, you need to apply the normalization.